# Django: How to efficiently filter model property methods?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I've been looking for a way to efficiently filter Django model objects using the `YourModel.objects.filter()` method with property values.

Django is unable to filter through property methods in this way.

It's still possible with list comprehension:

```
streams = [object for object in YourModel.objects.all() if object.property_method == 'value']
```

I've been told that this method isn't efficient because you still iterate through each object in the SQL table instead of the apparently more efficient SQL filter way.

Really I'd like to know what the best way to do this would be.

Here's my example models:

```
# someapp/models.py

from django.db import models

class Platform(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Account(models.Model):
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Account Name", max_length=100, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures', null=True, blank=True) 

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name

class Stream(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Host")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.host.name

    @property
    def platform(self):
        return self.host.platform
```

I'm thinking that it might just be best to make platform an attribute, but that kind of takes away the automatically adding part of it without external scripts.

What's the most efficient way to filter Objects (in this case "Stream" objects) by a property method? or is it better to do this a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't filter by a method since you can't translate that to SQL. That said, in the specific example you gave you can chain the filter statement.

This is what it would look like: `Stream.objects.filter(host__platform__name='value')`

For more context on how this works: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/join.html

Answer (score 1):

**Property** is defined in application level, if you would like to filter through **property**, you have to load the objects into Python to **evaluate the property** first then you can loop through. This is ideal for single object evaluation, while for multiple objects, you can always **delegate** the computation to db using  Queryset [annotation and aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate)

```
qs = Stream.objects.annotate(
    # you can annotate what you would like to compute in your model, not necessary a field
    platform = F('host__platform__name')
    ).filter(
    platform = 'value'
)
```

Then, each `Stream` object will have `.platform` attribute available. You can simply looping through the `annotated value` using **`[i.platform for i in qs]`**

A general situation could be:

```
Model.objects.annotate(
    <name> = <computed_value>
    ).filter(
    <condition> 
)
```